# How to find the names of all user-defined chains in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

Is there a good way to list the names of all user-defined chains in `iptables`? By user-defined I mean chains that were created with `iptables -N`.

The reason is that I'm writing a script to reset everything to initial state. In addition to resetting all built-in chains I want to also delete any user-defined chains.

So far I've only found `iptables -L`, but parsing this output seems like a bad idea. I've also looked in `/proc` and `/sys`, but I haven't seen anything useful there either.

Comment: The title is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). It's good you provided the context in the body of the question. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762184/432690) solves the problem (I think), but it does not answer the *title* at all. Unless you want answers that *strictly* answer the title, consider changing the title to something that describes the underlying problem, not what you thought the solution might be. I could do this, but *maybe* your real question is in the title (then you should emphasize you want exactly this). I cannot tell.

Comment: I think the title is appropriate because what I really want to know is the general solution. The answer by @user1686 is a particular solution (which is helpful in my current specific context) but it leaves part of question unanswered. I wrote my question intentionally in a way that can be answered both specifically and generally.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this, the closest I've come is to list all chain names: 
iptables -L | grep -oP "Chain \K.*(?=\()"

Answer (score 1):

[Existing scripts](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/iptables/trunk/iptables-legacy-flush) to reset everything to initial state use `iptables-restore` to load a complete ruleset. This automatically deletes all previous chains and rules; the state of iptables after performing a "restore" will be exactly like what's described in the file.